# Adding dependent jars for UDF in the PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've a UDF which I use to do custom processing on the records. In the eval function I am using a third party jar for processing. I saw the job jar file, but it does not include this dependency. Is there any way to include dependent jar in the job jar ?
(For testing I am running the cluster in the local mode).

Or can I use distributed cache to make the dependent jar available to the UDF ?

I've tried registering the dependent jars in the pig. For the first registered jar (all udfs are bundled in this jar) I do not face the issues. But for the second jar, I am facing issues when UDF tries to access the class from it.

```
REGISTER '/home/user/pig/udfrepository/projectUDF.jar'
REGISTER '/home/user/thridpartyjars/xyz.jar';
```

The logs I get on the console are like this :

> ```
> 2013-08-11 10:35:02,485 [Thread-14] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.xyz.abc.convertToOtherFormat(Lorg/DateTimeZone;)Lorg/DateTime;
>         at com.myproject.MyUDF.exec(MyUDF.java:70)
> ```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about REGISTER `'file:///home/user/pig/udfrepository/projectUDF.jar'` ?

Comment: Thanks Vinnie, I tried this way but doesn't work!

Comment: Well, I met with some similar problem when using Hive UDF but not PIG. Maybe you have refered to the [book](https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-pig-alan-gates-1st/chapter-5/user-defined-functions), right?

Comment: Yes definitely I've reffered to the book :-). BTW: I see that the file must be on the classpath otherwise it would have thrown NoClassDefFoundException isn't it. I believe there is some issue related method finding through reflection!

Comment: Can you paste the real jar name of `/home/user/thridpartyjars/xyz.jar`? In your case, it seems some version conflict.

Comment: Sure its : joda-time-2.2.jar

Comment: I agree with zsxwing - it's probably a version conflict. Any libraries that hadoop uses will always be loaded in a higher class loader than anything you register in your pig scripts. Most likely you'll need to compile your UDF against an older verion of joda.

Comment: Well it got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue I found resolved and documented here :

http://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/nosuchmethoderror-while-using-joda-time-2-2-jar-in-pig/